# Using argparse multiple positional arguments and make one of them "optional" to include in input

Tags: arguments, argparse

**Idea:** I'm trying to write a program that after using command line arguments it will send the arguments to database. There are 4 arguments - `username`, `email`, `address` and `version`. **All arguments except** `username` should be mandatory.

**What have I complished so far:**
My code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

        parser.add_argument("-u", "--username", nargs = '?' , help="Insert your username", action="store_true")
        parser.add_argument("uName", help="Insert your username", type=str)
        parser.add_argument("-e", "--email", help="Insert your email", action="store_true")
        parser.add_argument("eMail", help="Insert your email", type=str)
        parser.add_argument("-a", "--address", help="Insert your address", action="store_true")
        parser.add_argument("address", help="Insert your address", type=str)
        parser.add_argument("-v", "--version", help="Insert your app version", action="store_true")
        parser.add_argument("ver", help="Insert your app version", type=str)

        args = parser.parse_args()
```

So if I write cmd using all the arguments:

```
$python test.py -u tom -e tom@company.com -a 45xx -v 1.1
```

It gives me correct output. No problem.

Now, if I write cmd leaving one argument out:

```
$python test.py -u tom -e tom@company.com -a 45xx
```

It gives me error:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-u] [-e] [-b] [-a]
                          uName eMail aadress ver
test.py: error: the folowing arguments are required: ver
```

The way I understand it is that in my code all of them are positional arguments that are required to appear in the input and in my case all the "optional" arguments need a positional argument to save the input. Is it possible to make `username` argument that is not required in the input because the way I understand it in this case it is not and if thats true, can you suggest any alternative approach? Im thinking maybe there is a way to make `username` to give "Null" if its not in the input but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: 'store_true' arguments return `False` (default) or `True`.  They don't accept or require a following string.  `-u` and `uName` are independent arguments.  The use or not of 'u' has no effect on interpreting a string as a `uName' value.  You may need to reread the argparse documentation.

Comment: If you defined parser.add_argument("-e", "--email")` (default 'store' action) you wouldn't need an extra `eMail` argument. '-e tom@company.com' would just set `args.email` to `'tom@company.com'.

Comment: Thanks alot, that helped! Got it working.